# Access Forbidden when rewriting URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm using the following .htaccess code to fide the php extensions of my pages:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews
## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php [NC,L]
```

I can go to `localhost:80/site/page.php`, but when i try to go to `localhost:8/site/page`, XAMPP gives me an "Access Forbidden" error. What's happening here, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try your rule this way.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```